# Android - Save JSON from InputStream into String

Tags: java, android, json, inputstream

I'm trying to parse this JSON I get from a HttpURLConnection in Android.

```
{
"responsejson": 
    {
        "value1": [
            {
                "data": "Call",
                "label": "Call",
                "default": false
            },
            {
                "data": "Email",
                "label": "Email",
                "default": false
            }
        ],
        "value2": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Status",
                    "url": "/..."
                },
                "IsOpened": false,
                "IsDefault": true,
                "TechLabel": "NotStarted",
                "Id": "01Jb"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Status",
                    "url": "/..."
                },
                "IsOpened": false,
                "IsDefault": false,
                "TechLabel": "InProgress",
                "Id": "01Jb"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Status",
                    "url": "/..."
                },
                "IsOpened": true,
                "IsDefault": false,
                "TechLabel": "Completed",
                "Id": "01Jb"
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want to do is save the **content** of *value1* in a string, the content of *value2* in another string,... because I need to store it in the database, so in the future I can load and parse it. I am using JsonReader but it's not possible to do this with JsonReader.

```
// ...
inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
JsonReader json = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
json.beginObject();
while (json.hasNext()) {
    String valueName = json.nextName();
    // String content = ?????
}
json.endObject();
// ...
```

Any ideas? **Custom objects are not possible** due to we never know which values the JSON is going to show.

Comment: Why don't you create ArrayList and pass it to db class for processing ?

Comment: @Paritosh can you be more concise? I don't get what you said.

Comment: Create ArrayList<String> then add() items in it. Pass this ArrayList to you databaseInsertion(). Here you get() items from ArrayList and pass it to ContentValues or query...

Comment: I need to store as it appears in JSON because I never know how the JSON will be. Then, I will load it from db and parse it.

Comment: what do mean, the structure,should not vary that much

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert JSON array to string

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the
         * BufferedReader return null which means there's no more data to
         * read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder and returned as
         * String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson to parse the JSON that you receive in InputStream. Then you can get the ArrayList from that parsed object. Again, use Gson to serialize the arraylist back to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for your example json.

```
public class Value1 {
    public String data,label;
    @SerializedName("default")
    public boolean isdefault;
}
public class Value2 {
    public Attributes attributes;
    public boolean IsOpened,IsDefault;
    public String TechLabel,Id;
}
public class Attributes {
    public String type,url;
}
String jsonString = "{\"responsejson\":{\"value1\":[{\"data\":\"Call\",\"label\":\"Call\",\"default\":false},{\"data\":\"Email\",\"label\":\"Email\",\"default\":false}],\"value2\":[{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Status\",\"url\":\"/...\"},\"IsOpened\":false,\"IsDefault\":true,\"TechLabel\":\"NotStarted\",\"Id\":\"01Jb\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Status\",\"url\":\"/...\"},\"IsOpened\":false,\"IsDefault\":false,\"TechLabel\":\"InProgress\",\"Id\":\"01Jb\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Status\",\"url\":\"/...\"},\"IsOpened\":true,\"IsDefault\":false,\"TechLabel\":\"Completed\",\"Id\":\"01Jb\"}]}}";

    try {
        org.json.JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        jsonString = object.getString("responsejson");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject obj = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
    List<Value1> list1 = new Gson().fromJson(obj.get("value1"), new TypeToken<List<Value1>>() {}.getType());
    List<Value2> list2 = new Gson().fromJson(obj.get("value2"), new TypeToken<List<Value2>>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: Custom objects are not possible due to we never know which values the JSON is going to show.

Comment: You are right. The above code works only if json structure is known beforehand. I have written a new answer to support generalised json structures. Please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know json structure beforehand, your best bet is to use GSON 2.0 feature that supports default maps and lists.
Use the following code to deserialize :

```
Object object = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Object.class);
```

The created object is a Map (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap) which looks like this (for the above example)

> {responsejson={value1=[{data=Call, label=Call, default=false}, {data=Email, label=Email, default=false}], value2=[{attributes={type=Status, url=/...}, IsOpened=false, IsDefault=true, TechLabel=NotStarted, Id=01Jb}, {attributes={type=Status, url=/...}, IsOpened=false, IsDefault=false, TechLabel=InProgress, Id=01Jb}, {attributes={type=Status, url=/...}, IsOpened=true, IsDefault=false, TechLabel=Completed, Id=01Jb}]}}

Use the generated object, parse it and save it in your db.
You can serialize that map back to JSON using :

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

just read the stream regularly and save it into a regular String, then parse that String :

```
    // to get the general object that contains all the values
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json_readed);
    JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("responsejson");

    // to get the values
    List<JSONArray> all_values = new ArrayList<JSONArray>();
    Iterator<?> keys = response.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String value = (String)keys.next();
        if( response.get(value) instanceof JSONArray ){
            all_values.add(response.getJSONArray(value));
        }
    }
```

now you have all the values(whatever what's it's name id) combined into that ArrayList called(all_values).

Note that the JSON you provided in your question is missing opening"{" and closing"}" brackets in the beginning and the ending of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, first create a JsonObject from the json string representation, at this stage no specifics are given.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("json_here"); //catch all exceptions thrown.
```

Interestingly you mentioned that the structure varies, it consider that weird, i am guessing you are pulling from different api instances. What you need to do , create a pojo class mapping the api instance name to the returned json string body.

After you attained the Object of interest, consider using GSON. A Java serialization/deserialization library to convert Java Objects into JSON and back. What you then need to do is to,serialize the pojo class,into an object.Then store into the database. I recommend using realm and not SQLite.

Example serializing the class.

```
class JClass {
  private String jType;
  private String json_body;

  JClass() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

JClass j = new JClass();
j.jType ="some_type";
j.json_body = "json_body_here";
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(j);
```

then get the json String object, and store in database of choice.

Comment: for the json_body paramter , use object.toString(), from the JSONObject instance

Comment: the above approach, preserves the body of the returned json string, thus allowing you to manipulate has you wish. Just name the pojo class with jType, so when you reading back from db, you know how to parse the json. Make sure to store like a schema representation, GSON is even good for generating schema for a pojo class.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
* Method to parse InputStream to String JSON
* */
private String parse(InputStream in){
    StringBuilder result;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        result = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());
        return result.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();    
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(data); // data is JSON
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("value1");
    JSONArray msg2 = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("value2");
    Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        output.add(iterator.next());
    }
    String[] stringArray = output.toArray(new String[0]);
    return stringArray;

} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Answer doesn't explain value and type of `parser` and is useless without that information.